# Navigation Bar Transitions does not work, what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so basically I want to make my navbar slide in from the side of the screen when I click the toggle to open it, currently when I open the navbar it comes from the top and has no transition

If you want to understand more of what I mean exactly, check out https://iamtomwalker.com to see what I mean by having the navbar open from the side and transition in

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/JS files/style.css">
   
  <header id="home">
    <div id='nav'>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo_header">
          <h1 class="logo">Menu</h1>
          <button class="nav-btn" onclick="this.classList.toggle('change');">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <ul class="main_nav">
          <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services" class="scroll">services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="banner">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>scroll project</h1>
        <p>wsjnciunclsnjiemc ljfnjdc cinufifl,vlfldlvlekfopec ciun ck cipn i inrc cijan9pnc cipqe</p>
        <button class="scroll-link-btn"><a href="#tursr">Explore Tours</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="about" class="section">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>About Us</h2>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="services" class="section">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Services</h2>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="tours" class="section">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Tours</h2>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="section">
    <p>
      company that make this oen f
    </p>

    <a class="arrow-up" href="#home"></a>
  </footer>

  


  <script src='/JS files/js.js'> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my css:

```
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
  
.change .bar1 {
    transform: translate(0, 11px) rotate(-45deg);
}
  
.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}
  
.change .bar3 {
    transform: translate(0, -11px) rotate(45deg);
}

#nav{
    background-image: url("images/page.jpg");
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#home{
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
}
  
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}
  
.logo{
    margin-left: 5%;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.logo_header{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
  
.main_nav{
    display: flex;
    width: 333px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
}

.main_nav li{
    display: inline;
    color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.main_nav li a{
    color: black;
}

.nav-btn{
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}

.container{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 23px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.scroll-link-btn{
    background: none;
    border-color: white;
}

.scroll-link-btn a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.title{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#about{
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}

#services{
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    background-color:aliceblue;
}

#tours{
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}

footer{
    background-color:rgb(26, 62, 62);
    padding: 0.1px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.arrow-up {
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: -33px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 600px){

    .navbar{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100vw;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
  
    .main_nav{
        display: none;
    }
  
    .show_nav{
       display: flex;
       width: 100vw;
       height: 150px;
       flex-direction: column;
       justify-content: flex-start;
    }
  
    .main_nav li{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 25px;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 0%;
    }
    .nav-btn {
        margin-right: 5%;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;
        transition: all 0.3s linear;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
    }
    .logo_header{
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-right: 2%;
    }
    
  }
```

my js code:

```
const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-btn');
const linksContainer = document.querySelector('.navbar');
const links = document.querySelector('.main_nav');

navToggle.addEventListener('click',function(){
    links.classList.toggle("show_nav");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

top:-50px; for this navbar in class no active and if click on button class active go to navbar and margin-top:0px you can use a transition to very good style to navbar

Comment: excuse me, but I don't exact get what to do, can you show me pls ?